# sending XML file from IPhone to a server using Post Method

Tags: iphone, post, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send the data to server from my Iphone client. It works fine for most values but when itry to send a string like "IPhone+Cocoa" the server shows the string as "IPhone Cocoa". I have tried to google it but without success is there any why of doing it.

Here is my code

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSString *)aRequest
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kURLRequest]]; 
    NSString *httpBody =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",[requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[aRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *aData = [httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:aData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    self.feedURLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You do this for requestString and aRequest,but not after formatting together with your addition..

Try

```
httpBody = [httpBody stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

before

```
NSData *aData = [httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I tried it but without success. But when i pass the same request through browser to server it Works.

Comment: Its crashing... I think because it treat %3D as a format specifier but i used backslash for it..but this also didin't worked. Any idea..........How it can be done... Thanks For Replying